# Step back to previous content

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, kendo-ui, undo

I'm using template (kendo) for main content div ... when I click on some item, I replace this div with item detail, but when I want do undo operation, I can't. How can I do that?

```
<nav>
...
</nav>

<div id="content"> <- in this div I substituting content with template
    ...there are items....
</div>
...
```

Comment: If the content has been changed via ajax and something like `el.html(data);` It can't be "undone". But! You can find a way to keep a flag indicating what was the previous content with [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) and re-load it.

Comment: make use of $('#content').children().replaceWith( newContent ) after saving existing template content to some variable, then for undoing replace it from the stored variable